# Magento Service temporary unavailable

Tags: android, rest, magento, signpost

I'm trying to request the products from [Magento using REST-API](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/rest/introduction.html) for Android

I've create the authentication using [Scribe](https://github.com/scribejava/scribejava). I read that is not meant for Android, therefore, I searched more and found [signpost](https://github.com/mttkay/signpost).

here is my code

```
private void requestOAuth(String url)
    {
        OkHttpOAuthConsumer consumer = new OkHttpOAuthConsumer(MAGENTO_API_KEY, MAGENTO_API_SECRET);
        consumer.setTokenWithSecret(getAccessToken().getToken(), getAccessToken().getSecret());



        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addInterceptor(new SigningInterceptor(consumer))
                .build();

        final Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(url).build();
        try
        {
            Request signedRequest = (Request) consumer.sign(request).unwrap();

            Call call = client.newCall(signedRequest);
            Logger.i(TAG, ">>>> oAuth URL = " + url);
            Response response = call.execute();

            String responseString = response.body().string();
            Logger.i(TAG, "oAuth = " + response.code() + " oAuth Request ___ response  =  " + responseString);
        }
        catch (OAuthMessageSignerException | OAuthExpectationFailedException | OAuthCommunicationException | IOException e)
        {
            Logger.e(e);
        }

    }
```

I always get "Service temporary unavailable" and code 500.

I activated the guest to test it, and I found out that I **have** to send header "`accept`" > "`application/json`", otherwise it does **not** work as guest.

I've tried that while requesting with authentication, but it responded with something like "user role not available".

I've done the part in Magento where I create a role, give it permission..etc. (hence authentication is done and I've token and token secrete).

Can anyone suggest why it doesn't work?
I've been searching for days and trying a lot of things now, and nothing worked...

Is there any header that I must send?